# Grand Central Dispatch for Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

In Mac OS X I can take advantage of more than 1 core using GCD (Grand Central Dispatch). What is the equivalent for a Visual Basic program?

Comment: Your question would be improved if you explained exactly what GCD does.

Comment: [It looks like you can.](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/snowleopard/gcd.html)

Comment: Visual Basic .NET?  The [Parallel Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Extensions) is probably the closest equivalent.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752288/could-grand-central-dispatch-libdispatch-ever-be-made-available-on-windows).

Answer (score 1):

Threading in VB.NET can be very simple.

```
Shared Sub New()
    Dim t As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetWebpage)
    t.Start()
End Sub
```

All the above is doing is causing a function to be executed in its own thread.

Here's the function being called:

```
Private Shared Sub GetWebpage()
        Dim URL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AppCacheURL")
        Dim REQ As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL & "?Task=PopulateURLCache&Payload=App_Start")
        REQ.GetResponse()
End Sub
```

This is a simplified example of an asyncronous call to a function that fires an HTTP Request to a webpage. The original code is a little more complex with error handling and logging, but it basically causes a "keep alive" style aspx page to be accessed without slowing down the calling application. (Fire and forget)

**If you need a framework or library to accomplish your goals, have a look at:**

- [Parallel Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Extensions)
- [Task Parallel Library reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and [tutorial](http://codingndesign.com/blog/?p=195)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) and the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), both of which can be used to utilise the number of cores available in a host computer for performing CPU bound operations.

Joseph Albahari has a [great tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx) on using Parallel Programming techniques (in C#), but the exact same concepts apply to VB.NET.